# Any Eclipse plugin to view Assembly Code (not bytecode) for java files?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, assembly

I need to view assembly code of a java file during debugging. Is there any plugin present for this? If yes, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which assembly code are you talking about? The output from a Just-In-Time-compiling JVM?

Comment: @Michael Yes, I want to see the OPCODE DATA level code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't count on the code being compiled to machine instructions. The **just-in-time** (JIT) compiler might decide to interpreted your byte code instead. Or it might start out by interpritating it, and then later on compile some of it to machine instructions. It may even recompile it several times.

Comment: I don't know of JVM's offering this. If you find such functionality it would be a JVM specific thing. The bytecode is there to have the common platform - below that it gets very specific to the environment, and depends on the implementation approach.

Comment: [GNU `gcj`](https://gcc.gnu.org/java/) compiles java to native machine code, not just to java bytecode.  It's a traditional ahead-of-time compiler.  It's abandoned, though, so it probably still only supports Java 1.4.  And of course it won't produce the *same* machine code as the HotSpot JIT-compiler in the JVM you normally use, which can and does take advantage of things that are only known at run-time to make code that's optimized for that case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all java does not have assembly code, it has `byteCode` this is one of the requirement for Java to be machine independent. To know about `byteCode` check out this question

[Is it possible to view bytecode of Class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315938/is-it-possible-to-view-bytecode-of-class-file)

[Learning about Java bytecode and the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207124/learning-about-java-bytecode-and-the-jvm)

Comment: From bytecode JVM converts into machine level code. I need to view that machine level code.

Comment: @kajarigd From bytecode the JVM **might** convert your code into machine level, or it might just interpret the bytecode.

Comment: if you want to learn that, then read specification of JVM. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about an eclipse plugin, but you can make the VM display the generated machine code in the console. It requires some extra dll, see here: http://classparser.blogspot.ch/2010/03/hsdis-i386dll.html

Answer (score 0):

You can see assembly code using disassembly plugin.. search on Eclipse Marketplace.. this will give assembly code >>> http://andrei.gmxhome.de/bytecode/
And how about trying -XX:+PrintAssembly